# React text color not working on some android device

Tags: android, react-native

I am relatively new in react and I write very simple code like this to change text color.

```
<Text style={{color: '#EE7700'}}>5 JOBS</Text>
```

I can see text color is changed but on Galaxy Note 9, Android version 9, it is not working. (only show black color).

I also saw other people are having issues like this.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17139

How shall I do? Is it because of their device setting? Is there anything that I shall write more or shall check ?

Comment: What is the version of react-native?

Comment: React native version is 0.59.8. but I am using with Expo project. And SDK version is 35.0.0

Comment: Try https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/text-color , i tested also in my Oneplus Android 9 the basic sample and it works also

Answer (score 0):

You can try using styles instead of inline styling
like below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  JobsCount: {
    color: '#EE7700'
  },
});
```

and finally this

```
<Text style={styles.JobsCount}>5 JOBS</Text>
```

link to the provided answer

[Provided link to the above answer](https://snack.expo.io/r1DSwiLcH)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this problem using `RGB`.

```js
<Text style={{color: 'rgba(238, 119, 0, 1)'}}>5 JOBS</Text>
```